# Wix secure password within Orca

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

How can I secure a password so that it is hidden in Orca?

Comment: You can write a function which stores your passwords and returns it when called. Then pack it into dll-file and call from installer using CustomAction. In this case your passwords will be available only after dll decompilation and can't be seen using Orca.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, so it's a question of how secure you need to be.

If you want to secure the values from casual observers, use code such as the Crypto API to store the encrypted value in the property table at build time and decrypt it into another property at install time. This is not totally secure because a determined user could reverse-engineer your decryption code in the MSI custom action and figure out what you're doing. It's "security by obscurity".  You could perhaps obfuscate your code also.

Make sure you declare all the properties as Hidden in WiX so they are not exposed in an installation log file.

If this is a corporate environment, perhaps you could arrange to get the passwords from a secure location at install time, again into properties marked Hidden ao they are not in the MSI file at all.